# OpenSSL 1.0.2h gives different SHA256 values on different Windows versions?

Tags: c++, windows, openssl

How is it possible? I wrote a very simple test to demonstrate it:

```
vector<char> hash(SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH);
SHA256_CTX sha256;
SHA256_Init(&sha256);
SHA256_Update(&sha256, "abcdefghbcdefghicdefghijdefghijkefghijklfghijklmghijklmnhijklmnoijklmnopjklmnopqklmnopqrlmnopqrsmnopqrstnopqrstu", strlen("abcdefghbcdefghicdefghijdefghijkefghijklfghijklmghijklmnhijklmnoijklmnopjklmnopqklmnopqrlmnopqrsmnopqrstnopqrstu"));
SHA256_Final(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(hash.data()), &sha256);
```

On Windows 7 x64 the hash value is `cf5b16a7 78af8380 036ce59e 7b049237 0b249b11 e8f07a51 afac4503 7afee9d1`. It is the correct one.
Somehow on Windows 10 x64 Corporate the hash is `23d7f2dc 23d7f2dc e9af6f64 e9af6f64 5542bb78 23d7f2dc e8e3a3d6 e9af6f64`!!!
Why does OpenSSL give different (and wrong) hash versions on Windows 10?

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: Did you check return codes?

Comment: Sure, I check, they are nonzero.

Comment: Is it the same binary running on both, or did you recompile on each system? (i.e. is there any chance this is a bad build?) Windows does have its own SHA APIs but AFAIK OpenSSL doesn't use them, so I don't think that's a factor.

Comment: I use OpenSSL as a static library. I build EXE on Windows 7 and run the same binary both on Win 7 and Win 10.